# How can I get if a particular request has been completed using forkJoin in Angular 5 as part of parallel request processing?

Tags: angular, parallel-processing, rxjs, angular5, fork-join

I have a requirement to process the list of requests in parallel using forkJoin in Angular 5. I took reference from this link [RxJS recipes: ‘forkJoin’ with the progress of completion for bulk network requests in Angular](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/rxjs-recipes-forkjoin-with-the-progress-of-completion-for-bulk-network-requests-in-angular-5d585a77cce1)

I have one issue here. I am not able to get exactly which request has got completed but I am able to get the number of requests that have been completed.

How can I get to know which particular request has been completed?

Here is the code below

```
let Rx = window.Rx = window['rxjs'];
let {forkJoin, Subject, merge, of, defer, concat, throwError} = Rx;
let {ajax} = Rx.ajax;
let {map, filter, tap, takeLast, scan, startWith, mergeMap, finalize, ignoreElements} = Rx.operators;
console.clear();

function forkJoinWithProgress(arrayOfObservables) {

   return defer(() => {
   let counter = 0;
   const percent$ = new Subject();

   const modilefiedObservablesList = arrayOfObservables.map(
       (item, index) => item.pipe(
         finalize(() => {
           const percentValue = ++counter * 100 /  arrayOfObservables.length;
           percent$.next(percentValue);
         })
       )
   );

   const finalResult$ = forkJoin(modilefiedObservablesList).pipe(
     tap(() => {
       percent$.next(100);
       percent$.complete();
     }
   ));

   return of([finalResult$, percent$.asObservable()]);
 })

}

const getUserDetails = userIdsList => {

  const arrayOfObservables = userIdsList.map((userId, index) =>{
    //if (index === 1) return throwError({message: 'Vah-vah!'}); // testin with error

    return ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/' + userId)
  }
  )

  return forkJoinWithProgress(arrayOfObservables)
}


const result$ = getUserDetails([1, 2, 15]);

result$.pipe(
  mergeMap(([finalResult, progress]) => merge(
    progress.pipe(
      tap((value) => console.log(`${value} completed`)),
      ignoreElements()
    ),
    finalResult
  ))
).subscribe(values => console.log(values), console.warn);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to forkJoin documentation, it will wait for all of them to complete, and it maintains the order in which you lined up the requests, for the observables too.

> forkJoin will wait for all passed Observables to complete and then it will emit an array with last values from corresponding Observables. So if you pass n Observables to the operator, resulting array will have n values, where first value is the last thing emitted by the first Observable, second value is the last thing emitted by the second Observable and so on.

Full details: [Docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin) and a helpful [Medium article](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61)

So in your example, the order you loop through those userIds is going to be the order of the observables you get back.